# Selenium - Reduce findelement time

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When I run the `webdriver` it runs too fast.

The `webdriver` is moving the `next element` before the first one appears.

Can I make `webdriver` slower?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: As far as I understood, roey_r wants similar functionality like Selenium IDE has 'Speed control' bar.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using java, you can do implicit waits on every page found [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits)

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = driver.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
```

but a better way of doing this is by using fluent waits, to wait for a element to appear on the page, like this

```
public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    WebElement foo = wait.until(
    new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return driver.findElement(locator);
            }
            }
      );
                       return  foo;              
   };
```

and you can use it by

```
WebElement element = fluentWait(By.id("name"));
element.click();
```

This is a great answer to read over [answer to waits with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041013/selenium-webdriver-fluent-wait-works-as-expected-but-implicit-wait-does-not)