# Selenium implicit wait vs Thread.sleep()

Tags: dom, selenium-webdriver

According to selenium, an implicit wait polls the DOM for a certain amount of time to see if an element shows up.  My understanding is that it will poll up to a specified amount of time, but if an element shows up before, then it will continue without waiting further.

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html

I have a method that runs in about 13 seconds.  When I set the implicit wait to 100 seconds, it takes 213 seconds.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It appears that during this method, I'm waiting 2 times (100 seconds each).  Setting the implicit wait to 0 or 100 doesn't affect my method.  In both cases, they finish correctly.

My question is this.  I thought the implicit wait waits for the shortest amount of time for an element to show up.  Is this right?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Furthermore, why is it waiting 2 times, when it apparently does not need to wait?  (My method finishes correctly even if I set the wait to 0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [selenium webdriver - explicit wait vs implicit wait](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404160/selenium-webdriver-explicit-wait-vs-implicit-wait)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer:

implicit wait - It's global setting applicable for all elements and if element appear before specified time than script will start executing otherwise script will throw `NoSuchElementException`. Best way to use in setup method. Only affect `By.findelement()`.

`Thread.sleep()` - It will sleep time for script, not good way to use in script as it's sleep without condition.

Comment: What if the driver goto another url, is the implicit wait still effective? or do I need to recall it again?

Comment: ma, effective for the duration of the run regardless of URL.  Note that for findElements it is possible to expect size() == 0.  But Selenium will wait the last specified time.  If the page is loaded at the time of the test, reducing the implicit wait time (e.g. 1 second) before the findElements and then resetting back to normal afterwards will lead to faster execution times.