# "Sign in" button of a website is not getting clicked using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click the BUTTON in the HTML below,

```
<div class="row" id="signin-button-container">
    <button class="x2-button x2-blue" id="signin-button" style="border-color: #8d8d8d;;background: rgb(151, 151, 151); background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a1a1a1, #8d8d8d); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a1a1a1, #8d8d8d); background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a1a1a1, #8d8d8d); background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a1a1a1, #8d8d8d); background: linear-gradient(top, #a1a1a1, #8d8d8d);"> Sign in </button>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried all the selectors including the following:

```
WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(3));
WebElement signInButton;
try {
    signInButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.tagName("button")));
    System.out.println("Sign-in button successfully located.");
    signInButton.click();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Failed to locate the sign-in button.");
    e.printStackTrace(); // Print exception details for debugging
    return null; // Return null to indicate failure
}
```

I get "Sign-in button successfully located" consoled but still the button doesn't get clicked.

Comment: Take a minute to use an HTML beautifier, e.g. [this](https://beautifytools.com/html-beautifier.php), to make the HTML easier to read. Also, you need to add the exception/stack trace message to your question.

Comment: Seems the page code is not complete. Has your page more than one button? In that case you could not be sure using the tag name to click on the correct one. Please review and update your question being more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you ARE getting an error message. You check the logs and you get a message, "Sign-in button successfully located.", then a message, "Failed to locate the sign-in button.", and THEN the actual exception message printed to the logs. I'm assuming the error message is an element not interactable exception.

There are a number of issues that should be addressed to make this work and work better,

1. You don't get any error when you try to click because you are catching all exceptions

   ```
   catch (Exception e)
   ```

   A better practice is to only catch exceptions you are expecting and only if you plan on handling them. Eating all exceptions and printing a generic message is not very helpful when you go to debug... which you are experiencing right now. I would remove the `try-catch` and let the script fail when it throws. Continuing the script after an exception will likely cause it to fail later and then you'll have a harder time figuring out why it failed.
2. Your locator, `By.tagName("button")`, is way to generic. That's going to grab *every* BUTTON on the page, which depending on the page could be a LOT of BUTTONs. The HTML of the BUTTON you posted has an ID... you should always use that, `By.id("signin-button")`. It's likely you are grabbing *a* BUTTON but the wrong button and it's not visible or otherwise causing a failure and that's why you get the success message and then the failure message.
3. This message, "Sign-in button successfully located." is not really true. It just prints when the wait doesn't time out... it doesn't mean that it's found the correct element, which I'm assuming is what is happening here.

My suggestion is to reduce the code to the below,

```
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

...

String url = "https://staging3.rolustech.com:44353/index.php/site/login";
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get(url);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("LoginForm_username"))).sendKeys("username");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("LoginForm_password"))).sendKeys("password");
WebElement signInButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("LoginForm_password")));
signInButton.click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
signInButton.click();
```

If the code throws an exception, it will fail and get printed to the logs and you'll have the full exception message that you can review. Don't print success messages, they don't add any value. If your code gets past that line, you know it succeeded. Don't make yourself or others wade through hundreds of lines of success messages just to find the error message. It just prolongs the investigation time unnecessarily.

---

Other misc suggestions...

1. You define `wait3` at the top of the code but you aren't actually using it. Three lines below you use `wait` instead.
2. Three seconds is really short. I would do a minimum of 10s, depending on the scenario. If the element is immediately available, the code will not wait so it doesn't slow the code down. The only time it really slows down is if the element will never be available and you've specified a long wait time, e.g. 60s. Then it's going to wait the full 60s before it times out. You'll need to tailor the time to the scenario but my suggestion is for most scenarios, 10s is the right amount of time to wait.

Comment: I have tried all the locators bro. Its not working.
Anyhow, I have modified the code as per your suggestion. 

Please see the following image. You can see that there are no errors in console. 
It fills the usernam and password but never clicks on the button. 

https://imgur.com/0qZQQk8

Comment: There are no errors in the console because my code doesn't write anything to the logs. The problem is that there is a bug with the site. If you look at the Chrome console after clicking the Submit button you will see that there is an error, "error checking 2FA requirement". If you click the button again, then it actually processes the click. I've updated my code.

Comment: Even if I try to press "enter" key through the script twice. 
Still its not behaving as it behaves when clicked manually from mouse. 
Please see the image : 
https://imgur.com/DCZEbF4

Comment: None of my code suggests pressing Enter. As I said before, the problem is with the site and an error generated after clicking the "Sign in" button the first time. This happens manually as well. You have to click the button twice to get it to work with a brief pause between clicks. The code in my answer works. I've tested it several times. I've included the entirety of my code now.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Jeff but unfortunately its not working on my system.
I am using latest eclipse and Java as language. 

You can review it : 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10RRm3Lq0TbS9JrxXRCUFkuLZGsVNixAQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your code was still different than mine... BUT I just realized you asked the question about Java and I put python code for some reason. I've fixed that now. Just copy/paste the code exactly as I've written it and it should work.

Comment: Yes. Finally it has worked. But I need to understand why it worked. 
The most recommended way is to use Webdriver wait in java. 
e.g
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));

But this didn't work at all.

As I I introduced thread.sleep before the "2nd" click. It worked. But thread.sleep is not recommended https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975556/selenium-implicit-wait-vs-thread-sleep

Can we brainstorm on this?

Comment: You are correct in that a `WebDriverWait` is the best practice. The reason it isn't working in this case is because we're dealing with a bug. The first click doesn't work properly (but you still need a wait to wait to click the button the first time) so we have to click again. If you remove the sleep, two clicks with no pause between doesn't work so we need a static wait... that's where the sleep comes in. You should use it sparingly but sometimes it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to click an element using Selenium's `click()` or `ActionChains` class, as a last choice you can perform click action taking help of `Javascript`

Check the code below to click on an element using `Javascript`:

```
signInButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("signin-button")));
System.out.println("Sign-in button successfully located.");
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", signInButton );
```

Imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
```

**UPDATE:** I tried it manually clicking, it looks like it needs to be clicked twice for some weird reasons. Try to click it twice as below:

```
signInButton.click();
signInButton.click();
```

I tried the following code and it clicks on the desired button successfully:

```
driver.get("https://staging3.rolustech.com:44353/index.php/site/login");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("LoginForm_username"))).sendKeys("test");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("LoginForm_password"))).sendKeys("test");
        
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("signin-button"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("signin-button"))).click();
```

Comment: Tried it already. Didn't work.

Comment: Can you share the URL if it is not private?

Comment: https://staging3.rolustech.com:44353/index.php/site/login

Comment: Check the updated answer. Try it and let me know the status.

Comment: I have imported js executor too :
WebElement signInButton = driver.findElement(By.id("signin-button"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", signInButton);
signInButton.click();
signInButton.click();


Still Not working.

Comment: I managed to click it. Check the code in updated answer.

Comment: Its not working shawn. 
Can you please join to discuss this? 
https://meet.google.com/ewf-rhzk-dnr