# Mixing implicit and explicit waits

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

The [docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) say:

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain
>   amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are
>   not immediately available.

Sub-question:

In the case of `find_elements_by_` (plural), how many elements does `implicit_wait` wait for to exist before continuing with your script? Or does `implicit_wait` only work with `find_element_by_` (singular)? If so what do the docs mean by "or elements"?

From [an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174978/1898641) I read that it's best not to use both implicit and explicit waits in the same script, which I took notice of as I'd like the tests to be as robust as possible.

Since I know there are times I'll definitely need `WebDriverWait`, does this mean I need to get rid of `implicit_wait` in my `unittest` `setUp` method and instead employ `WebDriverWait` every single time I use any `find_element_by_` method?

(I'd rather not have to do this; although I suppose I could put each of the `find_element_by_` methods in my own custom functions -each wrapped in their own `WebDriverWait` -it feels like I shouldn't have to).

So my main question is:

Can I instead keep my `implicit_wait` in my test `setUp` method, and then only use `WebDriverWait` when it comes to `find_elements_by_` and other places where I know I need it?

Comment: I wouldn't mix the two. I would use `WebDriverWait` each time. Selenium has no idea about when *you* need to wait for an element to be in a *specific* state before it's usable. That's why the option is there. Besides, an implicit is going to wait until the element is *found*. An element being *found* **is not** equal to an element being *usable*.

Comment: +1 I didn't know there was a distinction. I'm starting to wonder why `implicitly_wait` is in the API at all! How would you check for an element being usable? I see `expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable` but not sure what else I'd use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [selenium webdriver - explicit wait vs implicit wait](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404160/selenium-webdriver-explicit-wait-vs-implicit-wait)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since I know there are times I'll definitely need WebDriverWait, does this mean I need to get rid of implicit_wait in my unittest setUp method and instead employ WebDriverWait every single time I use any find_element_by_ method?

Yes. As you've seen in the question you link to, if you use both types of waits, you're going to run into undesirable behavior. It's not just theoretical. I've experienced that behavior first hand, tried to debug it, found the question you linked to and then removed all implicit waits from my test suites.

I developed a [library](https://github.com/mangalam-research/selenic) to help with setting up the explicit waits (and do a bunch of other things). Assuming you already have a `driver` object that has the selenium web driver:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenic.util

util = selenic.util.Util(driver)

# This goes through util and uses the explicit wait set by util.
foo = util.find_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "..."))

# For special cases that take longer to give results.
with util.local_timeout(10):
    # The timeout is set to 10 for calls in this with block.
    bar = util.find_element(...)
# The timeout is restored to what it was just before the with.
```

There are some times when you don't need to use waits at all because *logically* if element A is present then B is also present, so you don't have to *wait* for it. For instance. if you want the parent of an element you've already obtained from Selenium, you can do `parent = foo.find_element_by_xpath("..")`.

As for the behavior of `find_elements`, it returns as soon as it determines that there is a result to return. This could mean getting only one element if later elements do show up after `find_elements` has found something to return.

Comment: re. your point about finding the parent of an element you've already obtained from Selenium, does that mean that all browsers always make the parent of an element DOM-ready and visible before the element itself?

Comment: I was talking about mere existence. If element X exists in the DOM tree and it is not the root of the tree, X's parent must be present in the tree. I would expect this to be true also for visibility, but I'm not certain that it holds in all cases. However, if you start looking at things like clickability then you better use an explicit wait. Some of this also has to do with the logic of the software being tested. If the app creates a <ul> element by inserting it into the DOM tree in one operation, then when I have found the first <li> in it, I know the other <li> elements are also present.

Comment: Great thanks. Hope you don't mind another follow-up question. re. `find_elements` returning as soon as it determines that there is a result to return; If e.g. the page is still loading, or AJAX is loading some stuff, how do you go about getting `find_elements` to return the maximum/final number of matching elements? Do you always have to `WebDriverWait` `.until` `find_elements == known_expected_num_of_elements`? Or how else is `find_elements` normally used, given that presumably most web apps are very dynamic?

Comment: Yeah, you have to look for a sign that the AJAX operation is over. What this sign may be depends on your application. It could be, as you suggest, checking a number of elements, or checking for the presence of an element which you know is the final one the AJAX operation puts out. (Like a footer at the end of a dynamic paginated table of data.) Sometimes this means designing your application for testability in mind.

Comment: I see from [the docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#fetching-a-page) that WebDriver may return control before the page has finished loading, so I'll apply your advice there too.