# Selenium does not recognize an element in some of the times

Tags: selenium, junit4, jmenupopup

I have an element that selenium doesn't recognize sometimes.
I'm using `implicitlyWait` of 10 seconds and when i'm runing the test sometimes it passed succesfully and the element is recognized, and sometimes it failes with error "No such element".
I tried to change the wait time to 20 seconds but it dosen't matter

Comment: Does that element appear in the screen? I mean "the screen" you see, not in the code

Comment: Yes, he exist all the time, 
I'm running the same test all the time

Comment: Does the web apply dynamic loading or lazy loading? Let your sel smooth run from bottom to top to find it in 10 seconds. May use While Loop

Comment: The web apply in less then 10 seconds, 
i'm seeing the element on the page but selenium doesn't recognize him

Comment: Waiting is not the solution, make your sel browser run bottom to top serveral times to find out the issue. This was my solution in the past. If it still don't recognize, try reload and find again if you sure the web have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using explicit wait :

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver,60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/a/i")));

Comment: I'm using implicitlyWait, 
why to use also another wait?

Comment: @Liorp please don't mix implicit and explicit waits for reference please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164742/combining-implicit-wait-and-explicit-wait-together-results-in-unexpected-wait-ti#answer-15174978

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue one time and I was facing this issue because I was was trying to select some option in the sub-menus using click to the main menu and then the sub-menu.
When used Actions class, the issue was resolved. 
This could be an issue for you as well.