# Get page source after each button click in a loop with get_elements_by_xpath using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to automatically download text files for ATS Blocks Download section on FINRA website. The problem is while I am able to click on the icon and open the file in the browser, I cannot get the page source after the click. `driver.page_source` returns the page source for the ATS Blocks Download section page (the one before the click).

Here is a piece of code I was trying out:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time 


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
URL = 'https://otctransparency.finra.org/otctransparency/'
driver.get(URL)

# Agree to the general terms
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn btn-warning"]').click()

#go to ATS Blocks Download section
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@href="/otctransparency/AtsBlocksDownload"]').click()

#wait for the page to fully load
time.sleep(5)

#click on each download icon
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@src="./assets/icon_download.png"]'):
    element.click()
    print(driver.page_source)
```

How to get the page source after every `element.click()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `page_source` of all the pages.
You need to
Induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`()
Induce `WebDriverWait` and `visibility_of_all_elements_located`()
Induce `WebDriverWait` and `number_of_windows_to_be`()

**Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
URL = 'https://otctransparency.finra.org/otctransparency/'
driver.get(URL)
driver.maximize_window()
# Agree to the general terms
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@class="btn btn-warning"]'))).click()

#go to ATS Blocks Download section
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//a[@href="/otctransparency/AtsBlocksDownload"]'))).click()

#click on each download icon
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//img[@src="./assets/icon_download.png"]')))

for link in range(len(elements)):
    elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//img[@src="./assets/icon_download.png"]')))
    elements[link].click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
    windowhandles=driver.window_handles
    driver.switch_to.window(windowhandles[-1])
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,"pre")))
    print(driver.page_source)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(windowhandles[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

After every time that you click element to download other browser tab is opened, in order to get the page source from the other tab use:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//[@src="./assets/icon_download.png"]'):
element.click()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.set_page_load_timeout(120)
print(driver.page_source)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
driver.set_page_load_timeout(120)
```

PS. Instead of doing the:

```
time.sleep(5)
```

You can do:

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(120)
```

Comment: Also instead of driver.page_source you can do driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/pre').text

Answer (score 0):

Be sure not to mix various "waiting" mechanisms, as it can result in unexpected behavior (See this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174978/8754516) for "why").

Be careful when using setting an implicit wait time, since once it is set, it is set for the lifetime of the driver instance ([source](http://www.aptuz.com/blog/selenium-implicit-vs-explicit-waits/), although it has been said in various places across the web).

If you intend to have your driver wait on multiple pages, you should use `WebDriverWait`. As shown in other replies, `WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)` accepts a `WebDriver` instance as well as an integer which represents the amount of time to wait before throwing an `TimeoutException`, in other words it accepts a timeout.

You can create a new `WebDriverWait` instance every time you're trying to find an element, without having to create a new `WebDriver` instance with a new implicit wait time. Since each element may need to waited on for a differing duration, this is ideal. You could go as far as to create a wrapper function to encapsulate the use of `WebDriverWait`:

```
def PatientlyClick(by, path, driver, timeout):
    WebDriverWait(driver,timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, path))).click()
```

The above snippet of code could be made prettier if you designed a class which encapsulated your `WebDriver` instance, but that might be unnecessary for your purposes (see [Page Object Model Design Pattern](https://blog.testproject.io/2019/07/16/develop-page-object-selenium-tests-using-python/)).