# How to wait element of a list is detroyed?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to click on all buttons in a table that delete their line :

```
    try:
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table//button[@class="deleteEntry"]')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("      [NoSuch] Buttons not found")
        return False

    for element in elements:        
        element.click()
        # How to wait element is destroyed ?
```

I must click on them one by one and wait one by one they are destroyed.
I know to locate and click on them, but how do I to wait they are destroyed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that after you click the Delete button, some element will disappear (either going invisible or removed from DOM).

You can try Explicit wait.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# get the element here
# elem_to_disappear = ...

# click delete button
del_btn.click()

# wait until the element is gone
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.invisibility_of_element(elem_to_disappear)
)
```

Futher document here: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element

Comment: Check the problem I had when I used `invisibility_of_element_located` with implicit wait https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373501/why-does-seleniums-wait-until-notec-invisibility-of-element-located-does-not It is better to avoid uding implicit wait at of if you are using `invisibility_of_element` and `invisibility_of_element_located`

Answer (score 0):

try `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately available.If it isnt work try `time.sleep(waiting_time)` from time library