# How to set seconds as variable in Implicit Wait

Tags: java, selenium, groovy, keyword, katalon

`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

> Is it possible to set '10' as variable so that it can be chabged dynamically? If possible how? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain
> amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are
> not immediately available. The default setting is 0, meaning disabled.
> Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the session.

It is set for life of webdriver session.

Coming to your question Is it possible to set '10' as variable ?

Yes it's possible.

```
int a = 10;

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(a, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

> wrap this line in a method and pass the int args if you have static driver reference like this :

```
public void wdImplicitWait(int duration){
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(duration, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

call it like this :

```
wdImplicitWait(5);
some web element interaction like click or sendkeys here
wdImplicitWait(3)
```

> if your driver is not static then, make sure to pass driver instance reference

```
public void wdImplicitWait(int duration, WebDriver driver){
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(duration, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

But there won't be any impact since it is set for entire life of `webdriver` for the particular execution.

so calling `implicitlyWait` again and again won't have any impact.

See what [official doc says](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#implicit-wait)

Comment: Hi @cruisepandey what do you mean by call it like this?. I tried wrapping it in a method but, when i called my `keyword` and change the `value` to 180 it didn't have any effect. Thank you

Comment: Can you share the wrapped code ? How did you determine that it didn't wait for 180 seconds ? Did you get any erro ?  Implicit wait says that whatever value you set, set it for life time of driver object which means that once driver is initialised and till the time it is closed or quit.

Comment: `public class ImplicitWait {
 public static WebDriver driver;
 int timeInSeconds = 0;
 @Keyword
 public void implicitWait(int timeInSeconds) {
  // Get active window
  driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver();
  //Specify implicit wait of 2 minutes
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }
}`

>Here is my code, i added this on my test case as custom keyword and change the input value to 180 and didn't wait for 3 minutes to click a certain button.

Comment: Calling `implicitlyWait` again and again will have an impact if you change the value in seconds. For example, if you set it to 0 in the middle of code  it will mean that there is no wait.

Comment: @vitaliis : Why not set it up once for life time of driver object ? and use explicit wait for specific waiting purpose ?

Comment: There are some corner cases when you need to change it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373501/why-does-seleniums-wait-until-notec-invisibility-of-element-located-does-not

Comment: @JohnPaulArcilla : I guess by seeing your code is that "You should opt for explicit wait instead of implicit wait"

Comment: It is recommended to to mix explicit/implicit waits in general

Comment: @vitaliis : there you had 10 seconds wait and it's obvious the nobody would want to mix explicit wait with implicit wait. But I see lot of folks like mixing both of them and always have undetermined timeout

Comment: @vitaliis : "Warning: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example, setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds."

Comment: @vitaliis : That is what official says :)

Comment: I faced unpredictable wait times only once. When you wait until an element is invisible.

Comment: @vitaliis : I believe we can not argue on this since that's what official says.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a method that will set an `implicitlyWait` accordingly to passed time duration it can be done as following:

```
public void setImplicitlyWait(Webdriver driver, int duration){
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(duration, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Depending on your actual project structure it's possible that you need to pass time duration only, do it will be like this:

```
public void setImplicitlyWait(int duration){
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(duration, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

However it's not recommended to use implicitly waits, explicit waits should be used.
Also, if you still want to define implicitly wait it is normally defined once per driver instance i.e. for the entire test life.

Comment: Thank you for answering @prophet but whenever I try to add `(WebDriver driver)` on the method Im getting an error message

Comment: Well, it depends on your project structure. It's possible that you should pass the time duration only.

Comment: Yeah I tried to use the `(int duration)` only but still it does not work and I don't know why. Sorry for the trouble its my first time to work with katalon.

Comment: I never used katalon, but so far I see pure Selenium issues, so... What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Because, it didn't wait for 3 minutes before proceeding to the next step which is to click a button

Comment: Well, I need to see your code to try answer

Comment: `public class ImplicitWait {  public static WebDriver driver;  int timeInSeconds = 0;  @Keyword  public void implicitWait(int timeInSeconds) {   // Get active window   driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver();   //Specify implicit wait of 2 minutes   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  } }`

Comment: timeInSeconds = 0;

Comment: But I changed the value into the input variable to 180.

Comment: This is what I see here. You didn't show all the code. Also pasting code as a comment not too readable..