# Selenium python random Jenkins pipeline fails

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem I cannot figure out how to solve as it occurs randomly.

I have a webpage on which I want to check always if everything is working, such as buttons, videos etc.

So I start using selenium and everything works just fine when I run it locally.

S I decided to automate those test by creating a Jenkins pipeline, and here is the weird thing, out of 16 pipelines, I have always random 2 pipeline that fails and times out always at the same point.

Let me give a bit more details:

one step that all the pipelines have in common is this:

```
Play video
(wait for the video to finish)
Press Next button
```

This bit of code is as follow:

```
# Play Button
time.sleep(5)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Play')]"))).click()
time.sleep(120)

# After Video Ends, click Next button
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click(
```

I am not an expert with Selenium, so this is the solution that I could think of.
The video plays just fine, always..but randomly it fails because it cannot find the `Next` button.

On step to debug this, is to take a screenshot and see what is happening. In the screenshot I could see the button, which mean the page was fully loaded. So I decided to increase the web driver wait time to `150sec` and yet the same error occurs randomly.

So I was wondering what else I can do to prevent those `False Positive` from happening?

I hope I made my point clear enough and please if I missed something or need more infos, just ask me.

UPDATE:
Thank you Tony for your help.
Just to make sure I understood the logic. This is the updated code.

```
driver.set_window_size(1920,994)
short_timeout = 100
long_timeout = 150

play = None

try:
    next = WebDriverWait(driver, short_timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Play')]")))
except TimeoutException:
    try:
        driver.get(driver.current_url)
        next = WebDriverWait(driver, long_timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Play')]")))
    except TimeoutException:
        pass

if next is not None:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", play)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", play) 

# After Video Ends, click Next button

next = None

try:
    next = WebDriverWait(driver, short_timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Next')]")))
except TimeoutException:
    try:
        driver.get(driver.current_url) # reload the current page
        next = WebDriverWait(driver, long_timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Next')]")))
    except TimeoutException:
        pass

if next is not None:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next)
```

the Try and except must be applied to every action I want to perform on that page, and if it timeout, it reload the page and try again.

There is only one thing that I am not sure I understood. The if statement for the scroll and click. I have to declare it for each try?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without having a minimal example to test with.

You shouldn't need your `time.sleep()` calls and instead use the ExpectedConditions fully. You're already using `presence_of_element_located` but as the docs state, this check doesn't ensure that the element is visible; and thus clickable.

> An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.

Try using [`element_to_be_clickable`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) which should check visibility and clickability:

> An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.

Also, be careful reusing your `WebDriverWait` object as they [chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65375095/11916773).

Comment: I am so sorry and I understand when you say that is hard to reproduce without any test. Sorry again for the poor request of help.
I changed the element to be clickable. Forgive me for asking this. So based on what you said. The wait is stackable, which mean it will keep adding 100secs for each `wait` that I declare right?
So if I keep `wait = WebDriverWait(driver,150)` and in my code I change the `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click()` to `wait.implicitly_wait(0)` it will use just the 150 of the driver, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

next = None
try:
    next = WebDriverWait(driver, short_timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Next')]")))                            
except TimeoutException:
    try:
        driver.get(driver.current_url) # reload the current page
        next = WebDriverWait(driver, long_timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Next')]")))
    except TimeoutException:
        pass

if next is not None:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next)
```

Other option is to use `next.click()` as you did but I learned that this sometimes doesn't work while executing a click via JavaScript always works.

Comment: Thank you so much mate, I did update my post with your code and asked for a question there as I am not sure I understood that bit

Comment: See updated answer. You could try the `next.click()` if it works as it is much shorter. Also I am not sure if you need to scroll down, this is just to be sure your element is visible and clickable. The code was for the `next` button as you said it gives the problems so you don't need to apply it to every element click. It's up to you.

Comment: Hey buddy, I tried your solution and configured the same thing for the Play button. When selenium reach that point, it just doesn't execute the `click`. Am I missing something? the if statement should go be before the try? Because the try works, at the timeout it refreshes the page but yet does not click

Comment: Try to create a sample code locally on your computer outside the pipeline ands debug and see if the `next` is not None, otherwise it will get to the exception to `pass`so nothing will happen. If next is not found then what is the reason for that? It is difficult to say without the full code and without knowing the structure of the page