# Wait javascript event WebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, bdd

I have a menu and sub-menus built in angularJS.

Each menu has the following code:

```
<a class="ng-scope" ng-click="irPara(item, $event)" ng-if="!item.heading" title="">
```

When I try to click in a link of a submenu, Selenium throws an exception that Element is not clickable, or element is not found.

I assume this happens because I have to wait submenu be load, how Do I wait for this submenu to be loaded without using Thread.sleep()

thanks

Comment: Try Using Explicit Wait...Hope It Helps;) is it angular js?

Comment: Implement a FluentWait: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404160/when-to-use-explicit-wait-vs-implicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver/12248779#12248779

Answer (score 2):

You can use explicit wait. Work around in JavaScript:

```
driver.wait(function() {
    return driver.findElement(locator).isDisplayed();
}, 10);
```

This will wait up to 10 seconds for the element to be displayed.