# Python Selenium how to locate element

Tags: jquery, python, html, selenium

How can I click via selenium and python on such element:

```
      <a href="#create" class="btn toolbarBtn">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Create
        </a>
```

When I Copy Xpath this element from Chrome i got this:

`//*[@id="page"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/i`

But when I use it in my code:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/i').click()`

I got error that:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="page"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/i').click()"}
```

When I tried to use `find_element_by_link_text` and `partial_link_text` I got same error that selenium was unable to find such element.

Comment: Are you sure about the xpath?is it really valid? could you please paste the link of the page here?

Comment: I can't paste link here because its under corporate network. But I think I found solution. Selenium is too fast, and I need to put implicitly_wait(10) somewhere in my code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to wait until element becomes clickable:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='#create']"))).click()
```

If this also doesn't work check whether your link located inside `<iframe>`. If so, you need to switch to that frame before clicking link:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("Put frameID here")
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case I found that selenium is going too fast, so some elements doesn't have time to load. When I put `sleep(5)` in the code the errors gone.

To avoid putting too many `sleep()` in my code I use `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` which resolved my problem definitely. I also dense my code a lot throwing up nearly all `sleep()` functions.

Thanks all for help!

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Comment: This is a less than ideal solution compared to using Selenium's built-in wait() function.

Comment: And why driver.implicitly_wait(10) is worse than explicitly waiting?

Comment: @heniekk, `ExplicitWait` provides with more options and flexibility. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404160/when-to-use-explicit-wait-vs-implicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver/28067495#28067495

Comment: @Andersson thank you for this. This information is very valuable for me. I marked your answer as approved. Update: but still I found Chloe comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404160/when-to-use-explicit-wait-vs-implicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver/28067495#comment46445762_28067495 valid in my situation. Implicite wait is much easier to use for me.

Answer (score -1):

please try below code

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Create").click()
```

Comment: There is no method `find_element_by_partial_link()` in `selenium`. Also there is no need to use search by partial link text as search by link text `"Create"` is more precise and it should also find the link

Comment: It should be `find_element_by_partial_link_text`

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this (I edited my question to address this), but I tried this one to.