# How to execute except code block faster in this case if elements is not found using Python/Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have this code below to get comments from a page. Sometimes there are no comments, hence the except code triggers. It tries the try code block for like 5-10 seconds before executing the except code. Is there any faster way to check if the elements is found or not? Preferably: If the elements is not found then execute the except code directly.

```
try: 
        comments = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, relativeXpathToReportComments)))
        # some code to be executed if the elements is found

except:
        print("could not find/get comments on comment page")
```

Comment: Do you know what that 20 means? and other driver configuration available about times?

Comment: I do not think we can do much here, you will have to wait 5-10 seconds in case of element absence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to check elements existence immediately you can simply use something like this:

```
if driver.find_elements_by_xpath('relativeXpathToReportComments'):
    # some code to be executed if the elements is found
else:
    print("could not find/get comments on comment page")
```

`driver.find_elements` returns a list of elements matching the passed locator.
In case there are such elements it returns non-empty list of found elements. Otherwise it returns an empty list recognized as `False` in Python.
`find_elements` and `find_element` are looking to find elements up to the timeout defined by `ImplicitWait` which is 0 by default.

Comment: `find_elements` will take exact same time from `ImplicitWait` there won't be any change

Comment: @cruisepandey the default value of `ImplicitWait` is 0

Comment: and You assumed that OP had set it to 0 ?

Comment: You do not need to set it to any value. It is 0 until you change it. So, since he didn't mention that - yes. It's not recommended to use `ImplicitWait` at all until you are aware what is it doing and how it works...

Comment: Where is it mentioned that it is not _recommended_ ? it's one of the famous wait Selenium has. To the real side, your solution will not make any time change with respect to time saving as same OP intended

Comment: @cruisepandey well, I was sure you know this.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28067495/3485434

Comment: read what official says here not some random one from SO - https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/