# How can I use Selenium to loop through rows in table and click on link in first row, scrape, then go back and click on next link and repeat?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape Basketball RealGM. I want to get the height, weight, age, and image URL for each player on a table. This is my current code but when I run it Chrome just keeps loading even after everything on the page has loaded. Also it never clicks on the link on that row like the `find_element` line tells it to. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am still fairly new to Selenium.

```
import pandas
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/international/league/4/Spanish-ACB/stats/2024/Averages/Qualified/All/points/PG/desc/1/Regular_Season'
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
rows = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
for row in rows:
    row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'nowrap tablesaw-cell-persist').get_attribute('href').click()
    driver.back()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I have found in past projects that trying to interact with things like clickable elements doesn't always work well. You could instead try getting the hyperref and just following it using `driver.get(url)`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you collect all the links first, and then reach them one by one.

With the current approach it will take much more time and repetitive work for the driver (re-searching table/rows/link after the driver.back())

You are not using explicit waits in your code. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28067495/23182657) to understand why the implicit wait is a bad practice.
Also, don't rely much on multiple classes, they or their order may be changed easily.

The following code sample works fine for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

try:
    driver.get("https://basketball.realgm.com/international/league/4/Spanish-ACB/stats/2024/Averages/Qualified/All/points/PG/desc/1/Regular_Season")

    # find table
    table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[contains(@id, 'table')]")))
    # find all rows
    rows = table.find_elements(By.XPATH, "./tbody/tr")

    # iterate over rows and collect the links
    hrefs = []
    for row in rows:
        link = row.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(@href, '/player')]")
        hrefs.append(link.get_attribute("href"))

    # iterate over each href, and collect the data for each player
    players_data = []
    for href in hrefs:
        driver.get(href)

        player_card = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'profile-box')]//div[contains(@class, 'half-column-left')]"))
        )

        # collect player data (trim the required parts)
        name = player_card.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h2").text
        img_src = player_card.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "img").get_attribute("src")
        born = player_card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//strong[text()='Born:']/parent::p").text
        anthropometry = player_card.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//strong[text()='Height:']/parent::p").text

        players_data.append({
            "name": name,
            "img_src": img_src,
            "born": born,
            "anthropometry": anthropometry,
        })
        print(f"Player collected: {name}")

    print(f"\nAll players collected {len(players_data)}")
    print(players_data)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Also, I'd recommend you learn about [Beautiful Soap](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). With BS you can do the same job, but much faster.